# RegEx to remove background color and color property but leave all styles in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, preg-replace

I am still not able to use regular expressions by heart, thus could not find a final solution to strip out background color,font-family and color property from table with RegEx, but leave all styles

I have tried regular expression to remove all styles except color and background property.
But actually I want to remove background color,font-family and color property but leave all styles

```js
if(isset($_REQUEST["Save"])) {
    $VariantName = $_REQUEST["name"];
    $desc = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+\s+)(?:style\s*=\s*"(?!(?:|[^"]*[;\s])color\s*:[^";]*)(?!(?:|[^"]*[;\s])background-color\s*:[^";]*)[^"]*"|(style\s*=\s*")(?=(?:|[^"]*[;\s])(color\s*:[^";]*))?(?=(?:|[^"]*)(;))?(?=(?:|[^"]*[;\s])(background-color\s*:[^";]*))?[^"]*("))/i', '', $VariantName);
    echo $desc;
}
```

This

```html
<p style="font-family:Garamond;font-size:8px;line-height:14px;color:#FF0000;background-color:red;">example</p>
```

should become:

```html
<p style="font-size:8px;line-height:14px;">example</p>
```

Comment: If you use something like DOMDocument, you can do this properly as it understands the data structure and context.  At the moment using regex's is more of a hack and prone to future changes causing it to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend this but you can use this regular expression to remove the `CSS` props you want:

```
/(background-color|color|font-family)\:\#?\w+\;/i
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
            //Enter your code here, enjoy!
    $string = '<p style="font-family:Garamond;font-size:8px;line-height:14px;color:#FF0000;background-color:red;">example</p>';
    $pattern = '/(background-color|color|font-family)\:\#?\w+\;/i';
    $replacement = '';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```